# Not able to find SonarQube Service Connection in Azure Devops in new service connection list

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-devops-extensions

Tried looking all over couldn't find the option or the solution to get the option, any inputs would be deeply helpful.

[image]

My Azure DevOps Version:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the Azure DevOps is the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [SonarQube extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube):

[image]

After that you will see it:

[image]

Comment: ah..I thought that the extension is different than the service connection, are you sure about this ??

Comment: @Venky I almost sure! just try to install :)

Comment: Extensions can publish new types of service connections. The SonarQube extension includes a service connection definition.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install these both extensions

sonar cloud -- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarcloud

sonar qube -- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube

after that you can see the service endpoints.