# Create a service connection in Azure Devops to SonarCube via API

Tags: azure, sonarqube, connection, endpoint

I want to create a service connection in an Azure project to SonarCube via API. What type to specify in the 'type' parameter and what does the request body look like?
Using this to create a service endpoint.
HTTP:
"POST [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2"](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2%22)

Comment: [Combining SonarQube and Azure DevOps](https://msftplayground.com/2019/02/combining-sonarqube-and-azure-devops/) and [Adding a new SonarQube Service Endpoint](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/azuredevops-integration/#:~:text=In%20Azure%20DevOps%2C%20go%20to,Then%2C%20click%20Save.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to find SonarQube Service Connection in Azure Devops in new service connection list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744287/not-able-to-find-sonarqube-service-connection-in-azure-devops-in-new-service-con)

Answer (score 0):

The 'type' parameter should be set to 'sonarqube' and the request body should look like this:

```
{
    ...
    "authorization": {
        "scheme": "UsernamePassword",
        "parameters": {
            "username": <YOUR_SONARQUBE_TOKEN>,
            "password": null
        }
    },
    "serviceEndpointProjectReferences": [
        {
            "description": <AZURE_DEVOPS_SERVICE_CONNECTION_DESCRIPTION>,
            "name": <AZURE_DEVOPS_SERVICE_CONNECTION_NAME>,
            "projectReference": {
                "id": <AZURE_DEVOPS_PROJECT_ID>,
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": <AZURE_DEVOPS_SERVICE_CONNECTION_NAME>,
    "type": "sonarqube",
    "url": <YOUR_SONARQUBE_URL>,
    ...
}
```

You can find more details about the other parameters for the request body on the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#endpointauthorization